# Crashlytics Unity Plugin - export to Android Studio

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-fabric

I integrated Crashlytic plugin into my Unity project. It work fine if I build an APK file directly from Unity.

But if I use option export to "Google Android Project" in Unity

-> Then open Android Studio, select "Import project (Eclipse ADT, Graddle, etc)"

-> Run

-> App crash on Launch with exception: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.fabric.unity.android.FabricApplication"

Here's my **build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xct.poke.khongchien"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile project(':answers')
compile project(':an_social')
compile project(':beta')
compile project(':common')
compile project(':crashlytics')
compile project(':crashlyticswrapper')
compile project(':fabric')
compile project(':fabricinit')
compile project(':facebookandroidsdk470')
compile project(':facebookandroidwrapperrelease')
compile project(':googleAIDL')
compile project(':googlePlay')
compile project(':unityadsrelease')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'
compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.2.0.jar')
compile files('libs/EtceteraPlugin.jar')
compile files('libs/mobilenativepopups.jar')
compile files('libs/Prime31UnityActivity.jar')
compile files('libs/unity-classes.jar')
compile files('libs/WebViewPlugin.jar')
}
```

Anyone got this problem before?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Is that your app's build.gradle or project's build.gradle?

Comment: Hi Mike, It's my app's build.gradle, and class io.fabric.unity.android.FabricApplication should be in project "fabricinit".

Comment: @MikeBonnell did you have any info on this?

Comment: @plainjimbo I haven't been able to reproduce this unfortunately. Can you share more details specific to your instance of this?

Answer (score 11):

**==TLDR==**

You need to configure Unity's Android *Build Settings* to customize the `build.gradle` file and emit a `proguard-user.txt` file when it exports the project:

1. Click the *File* Menu -> click *Build Settings* menu item -> select *Android* in the *Build Settings* window
   [image]
2. Change *Build System* to *Gradle* and check the *Export Project* box
3. Click *Player Settings* button
4. Click *Publish Settings* in the *Player Settings* inspector tab
   [image]
5. Check both *Custom Gradle Template* and *User Proguard File* boxes under the *Build* section
6. Select *Proguard* for *Release* under the *Minify* section
7. Edit the `Assets/Plugins/Android/mainTemplate.gradle` and `Assets/Plugins/Android/proguard-user.txt` files to look like the ones below.

**mainTemplate.gradle** should have this in the `buildTypes` `release` section:

```
release {
  minifyEnabled true
  useProguard true
  proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt', 'proguard-user.txt'
}
```

**proguard-user.txt** looks like this:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**
```

**==Specifics for my situation==**
I was having a similar problem trying to export the project using the Gradle Build System in Unity. The terminology is a bit different, but it might be because I'm on a different Unity version (2017.1.1f1).

Also, rather than trying to import to Android Studio I'm trying to build from the command line using Gradle.

I was getting the following error while trying to do a `gradlew assembleRelease`, which is similar, but different:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application io.fabric.unity.android.FabricApplication: io.fabric.unity.android.b: Could not instantiate kits
....
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "..."]]
```

I noticed the `release` `buildType` in the root `build.gradle` was defined as follows:

```
    release {
      minifyEnabled true
      useProguard true
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
    }
```

In a blog article from [Kongregate on Unity](http://blog.kongregate.com/dealing-with-the-64k-method-limit-in-your-unity3d-game/), where they talk about the problems with exporting your Android project, they mention (take note of the last bolded sentence):

> We specified two ProGuard configuration files – the standard one that’s included with the Android SDK (proguard-android.txt) and one which is exported with the Unity Project as of Unity 5.4, (proguard-unity.txt). **You almost certainly need to maintain another ProGuard configuration file with rules specifying which classes and methods need to be kept for the plugins your game uses.**

Thankfully, @MikeBonnell pointed me to the Fabric Android Crashlytics integration docs which tells you [how to exclude Crashlytics from minification](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/dex-and-proguard.html#exclude-crashlytics-with-proguard) in your ProGuard file and that [you must have `minifyEnabled: true`](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/dex-and-proguard.html#gradle) in your build.gradle file if you're using Gradle.